# Ruby gem to change irb output font-size and color?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, terminal, irb

Can any body guide me to `ruby gem` that changes font-size and color of `irb` terminal output dynamically. If not `gem` is there any other method to lighten up terminal and/or irb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can try to use [pry](http://pry.github.com). It's alternative to `irb` shell. It has colorized results out of the box and much more.

There is [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails) about it.

Answer (score 0):

I asked DuckDuckGo and it told me that you should look at: [fancy_irb](https://github.com/janlelis/fancy_irb)

```
$ sudo gem install fancy_irb
$ irb
> require 'fancy_irb'
=> true
> FancyIrb.start
=> "Enjoy your FancyIrb :)"
```